# Building a kernel module from newer kernel for older kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, codec

I have a Sound Codec that was added in Kernel 4.9 (NAU8810) and I have a device that runs kernel 3.12. 
The provisions of upgrading the kernel to 4.x is very complex, and involves thousands and thousands of units already in the field which logistically is a nightmare, just to add a codec file in.

Is there a way to compile a module like that for 3.12 and run it on 3.12?

Thanks

Comment: Is back-porting the kernel module an option?  This module would most likely require source changes.  You could look for a 3.12 module that is most similar to the sound codec module and adapt it.

Comment: What you want to do is called *backporting* a module.  Success depends primarily on what external dependencies the module has, and how those dependencies differ between kernel versions.  Be aware that kernel APIs to userland are tightly controlled, whereas internal kernel interfaces can change more readily.  See https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: v3.12 is being still supported by someone. So, try to find the latest **v3.12.y** and back port your driver there.